# how to add dynamic data in a highchart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, data-visualization

I have a Highchart that is receiving JSON data via AJAX and jQuery.  But my chart doesn't show the points until I hover the mouse over the chart.  Even then the points are all at the very top of the chart.  I don't think I'm adding my points to the series correctly.  Please tell me what I'm doing wrong in the jsonpcallback function.

Thanks!

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
    <!-- Begin Chart options-->

    // define the options
            var options = {
                            chart: {renderTo: 'container'},
                            title: {text: 'Brewery'},
                            subtitle: {text: ' '},
                            xAxis: {text: 'Time',type: 'datetime'},
                            yAxis: [{ // left y axis
                                        title: {text: 'Temperature (℉)'},
                                        labels: {align: 'left', x: 3, y: 16,
                                                formatter: function() {
                                        return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 0);}
                                    },
                                    showFirstLabel: false}, 
                                    { // right y axis
                                        linkedTo: 0, gridLineWidth: 0, opposite: true,
                                        title: {text: 'Temperature (℉)'},
                                                labels: {align: 'right', x: -3, y: 16,
                                                    formatter: function() {
                                        return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 0);}
                                    },
                                    showFirstLabel: false
                            }],
                            legend: {align: 'left', verticalAlign: 'top', y: 20,
                                    floating: true, borderWidth: 0},
                            tooltip: {shared: true, crosshairs: true},
                            plotOptions: {  series: {cursor: 'pointer',
                                                    point: {events: {
                                                    click: function() {
                                                    hs.htmlExpand(null, {
                                                    pageOrigin: {
                                                        x: this.pageX, 
                                                        y: this.pageY
                                                    },
                                                    headingText: this.series.name,
                                                    maincontentText: Highcharts.dateFormat('%A, %b %e, %Y', this.x) +':<br/> '+ 
                                                    this.y +'(℉)',
                                                    width: 200});
                                                    }}},
                            marker: {lineWidth: 1}}},
                            series: [   {name: 'Hot Liqour Tank'},
                                        {name: 'MashTun'},
                                        {name: 'Brew Kettle'},
                                        {name: 'Post Chiller'},
                                        {name: 'Control Box'}
                                    ]
            };
    <!-- End Chart Options -->
    var chart;
    //after DOM is loaded setup timeout to call the ajax method
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //call function to render the chart and setup the options
        renderChart();
    });

    //this function requests the data
    function reqData(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://192.168.0.11/"+Math.random(),
            dataType: "jsonp",              
            jsonp: "callback",
            jsonpCallback: "jsonpcallback"
        });
    }

    function jsonpcallback(rtndata) { 
        for(var i = 0; i < rtndata.length; i++){
            if(rtndata[i].sensor=="hlt")
            {
                chart.series[0].addPoint([rtndata[i].time, rtndata[i].temp]);
            }
            else if(rtndata[i].sensor=="mt")
            {
                chart.series[1].addPoint([rtndata[i].time, rtndata[i].temp]);
            }
            else if(rtndata[i].sensor=="bk")
            {
                chart.series[2].addPoint([rtndata[i].time, rtndata[i].temp]);
            }
            else if(rtndata[i].sensor=="pc")
            {
                chart.series[3].addPoint([rtndata[i].time, rtndata[i].temp]);
            }
            else if(rtndata[i].sensor=="box")
            {
                chart.series[4].addPoint([rtndata[i].time, rtndata[i].temp]);
            }       
        }
    }

    function renderChart(){
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    }

    //continually poll for data
    setInterval(reqData, 5000);
    </script>
```

Comment: Did you try using console.info or console.log statements to log what you're doing? Perhaps using a debugger like Chrome Dev tools or Firebug will help show you what you're doing wrong. Also, post a link to the site so we can see what's happening. Thanks!

Comment: To answer this question, it is required to know the structure of JSON? What is inside rtndata? As it is not possible for us to know what is returned by JSON

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are nearly there; the only piece i believe you are missing is an *initial* call to your **regData** function from the chart's *load event*.

So to your second line after *define the options*, change this line:

```
 chart: {renderTo: 'container'},
```

to this:

```
chart: {renderTo: 'container', events: {load: regData}},
```

Answer (score 1):

Try converting the time strings to Javascript datetime objects. Highcharts will then read the datetimes correctly. For example, if the JSON date is in the format 'YYYY-MM-DD' you can use this code:

```
    var dates = [];
    $.each(jsondata[0], function(itemNo, item) {
        year = parseInt(item.split('-')[0], 10);
        month = parseInt(item.split('-')[1], 10);
        day = parseInt(item.split('-')[2], 10);
        dt = Date.UTC(parseInt(year), parseInt(month), parseInt(day));
        series[0].data.push([dt, parseInt(jsondata[2][itemNo], 10)]);
        series[1].data.push([dt, parseInt(jsondata[1][itemNo], 10)]);
        dates.push(dt);
    });

    options.series = series;
```